# final Entity with try catch in Java

Tags: java, exception, final

This is my code:

```
    SomeResult result = null;

    try {
        if(isOK) {
            result = service.getOK();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //logging
    }

    if(result == null) {
        result = service.getKO();
    }

    return result;
```

I want to make SomeResult result **final** like this:

```
final SomeResult result;
```

It is possible with **one** exit-point?

Comment: Sorry friend, your question isnt clear enough to understand. Can you try rewriting and explain what you want? apologies if English is not your first language

Comment: This sounds like a XY problem, why you need this `final`, please elaborate what and why you need not how you are trying to achieve it.

Comment: If you switched to Scala, you could use the functional `Try`. Java's "imperative try" doesn't have that ability though, since it operates entirely through side effects.

Comment: I open for editing to make it more clearly

Comment: What do you mean by "one return point"?

Comment: I guess you have to extract your code into a helper method, if you want a single return point. But this won't change much ...

Comment: I think one exit-point sounds better. Method has only one "return". It my  mistake.

Comment: What does the exception handler do?

Comment: Catch exception just for logging

Comment: Why are you trying to make a mutating variable `final`, just so that you can return it? I can't see any value in that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This could be done with a library like [vavr](http://www.vavr.io/), which implements the `Try` monad (i.e. turning the `try-catch` statement into an expression):

```
public SomeResult getResult() {
    final SomeResult result;
    result = isOK ? Try.of(service::getOK).getOrElse(service::getKO) : service.getKO();
    return result;
}
```

But then, what's the point of assigning the value to a local variable? It would be just the same as returning it immediately:

```
public SomeResult getResult() {
    return isOK ? Try.of(service::getOK).getOrElse(service::getKO) : service.getKO();
}
```

... in case of which, you might want to prefer [Joop's answer with multiple `return` statements after all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46058149/521799), which doesn't rely on a third party library.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of assigning to `result`, substitute `result =` with `return`. In effect removing `result`.

That semantically is actually a kind of "finally."

Answer (score 0):

```
final SomeResult result = getResult();
public SomeResult getResult(){
    SomeResult result = null;
    try {
        if(isOK) {
            result = service.getOK();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //logging
    }

    if(result == null) {
        result = service.getKO();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Check this link to see a final variable being assigned using a method call. https://ideone.com/UAoBTn

Comment: Yes I have compiled it and run it. This one line was missing that i have added as the first line in the method above.

Comment: That is when you return a value from method you can put it in a final variable while defining the variable. Once defined you can redefine that variable.

Comment: That is you need to make adjustments to your code according to your needs but this is a working code. Let me share another code snippet. Because I did not have this service.getOK and SomeResult so i can compile this exact code but the idea that you can assign a returned value from a method to a final variable that is a working solution.

Comment: It compiles but you miss the compile-time check of having `result` not null, so IMO the solution with multiple return points is better because it checks at compile time that every paths return something.